# Is it possible to dynamically render React components based on a state?

Tags: reactjs

This case is extremely dynamic. We have a web-app builder in Angular and we're migrating it to React. We're stuck at this point.

We have a form that has three fields:

```
<Module />
<EntityType />
```

Module field and entity type field are both static. They are simple select controls. Based on the value chosen from them, we need to render the field for the selected entity type.

For example, user selects `Blog` as the module, and `Author` as the entity type, we should show `<BlogAuthor />` field. Or user selects `Products` module and `Brand` entity type, we should show `<ProductsBrand />` field.

I did this part:

```
const [module, setModule] = useState()
const [entityType, setEntityType] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    import('AllFields')
    .then(fields => {
        const key = `${module}${entityType}`
        const field = fields[key]
        // how can I render field after the <EntityType />
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
}, [module, entityType])

return <>
    <Module />
    <EntityType />
</>
```

If I use `useState` to store the `field` and render it using `{field}` syntax, since some fields have `useEffect` inside them I get this error:

> Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

> Uncaught Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.

What should I do here?

**Update**

The `AllFields` is created dynamically based on the modules installed in the web application, and all entity types present. And it has a barrel configured for it.

Comment: Why not statically import them and use conditions?

Comment: Because this web-app builder is not used by one project and one customer. It's an infrastructure that supports hundreds of web-apps, each with separate set of modules. This means that we can't *statically* do anything here.

Comment: @DanielA.White, in other words we can't use `import { BlogAuthor } from 'Blog'` because one project might not have blog at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems alright so far, you've only missed few things.
Let's say we have a file with multiple exports (I believe it's what you have):

**Test.js:**

```
export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>test</div>
  );
};

export const Test1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>test1</div>
  )
}
```

Now in your generator component you can import `Test.js` and render components by accessing their names as a key:

**Component.js:**

```
const [component, setComponent] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  import('./Test.js')
    .then((module) => {
      // as a property accessor you have to pass a component name here
      const MyComponent = module['Test1'];
      setComponent(<MyComponent />)
    });
}, [])

return (
  <div className="App">
      {component}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Does it not produce the same error? Please add a `useEffect` to your components inside the `Test.js` file.

Comment: It doesn't throw the error from your example, as `<MyComponent />` is not getting called unless it's injected into the DOM using `{component}`.

Comment: The method is interesting and efficient